# Python: How to turn a string of binary values (arbitrary length) into hex data?

Tags: python, binary, hex, string-conversion

I need to turn a string like `data = "00000111010110101"` into a hex string, in this example I need '075A80'

You may notice a few caveats:

- leading zeros should not be stripped so hex(int(data,2)) doesn't work for me
- if len(data) %8 != 0 the string should be appended with zeros to end with a full byte

After searching this forum and hacking together different answers, this is one way I found to do it, but it seems rather complex and I hope someone else sees a much simpler way.

```
data_hex = "".join([ "%02X" % int("".join(a),2) for a in izip_longest(*(iter(data),)*8, fillvalue='0')])
```

Thanks!

Edit: Some background on the data. The underlying data is purely bits, it does not represent an integer or other numeric value, so the leading zeros are relevant and must be represented in the result. Also appending zeros at the (right) end doesn't change the "value" in my use case.

Comment: Also, I can only use Python 2.7.

Comment: `00000111010110101` bin is `eb5` hex so I'm not really sure how you get `075A80`.

Comment: `0x075A80` is `1110101101010000000` in binary. Looks like you're missing some zeroes on the right hand side.

Comment: From the question "if len(data) %8 != 0 the string should be appended with zeros to end with a full byte"

Comment: Yes, but typically "end" means "left hand side" in this context. If you append to the right, then the value of the number will change, which is a very unusual thing to do when you're just trying to display something.

Comment: Leading zeros on a binary string are just zeros. It wont **matter** if they are stripped or not. `0001234` is the same decimal number as `1234`. In the same way `00000111010110101` is the same binary number as `111010110101`. `hex(int(data, 2))` works just fine for you, it *doesn't strip zeros*.

Comment: You could use the string formatting expressions here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings

Comment: I'm not saying it makes sense, but "the string should be appended with zeros" is pretty clear, he wants it appended on the right.

Comment: Basically the bits should be consumed left-to-right, turning 8 bits at a time into hex equivalent. If there are less than 8 bits left at the end, extend with zeros to get a full byte.

The underlying data is bits, it does not represent an integer or other numeric value, so the "value" is preserved only when padding on the right.

Comment: @F.J: And to come to `0x075A80` you need 7 extra zeros, making the number a 24-bit binary value, which sorta makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option:

```
>>> data = "00000111010110101"
>>> new_data = data + '0' * ((8 - len(data)) % 8)
>>> '{0:0{width}x}'.format(int(new_data, 2), width=len(new_data) / 4)
'075a80'
```

The first line appends zeros so the length is a multiple of 8, and the second formats your hex string.

Comment: I like this answer, I wanted to avoid any conditionals. I also wanted to avoid any pre-formatting but I think caveat #2 sort of demands it. Also this answer cleanly deals with any size input, with the width in the format string. Thanks.

Comment: Any reason the % 8 is performed on (8 - len(data)), instead of just (len(data) - 1) ?

Answer (score 1):

0-pad your input to a multiple of 8, *then* turn it into a hex value:

```
multiple, remainder = divmod(len(data), 8)
if remainder:
    data = format(data, '<0{}'.format((multiple + 1) * 8))
result = format(int(data, 2), '0{}x'.format((multiple + 1) * 2))
```

The output is padded as well to give 2 hex characters per full byte.

This gives:

```
>>> data = "00000111010110101"
>>> multiple, remainder = divmod(len(data), 8)
>>> if remainder:
...     data = format(data, '<0{}'.format((multiple + 1) * 8))
... 
>>> format(int(data, 2), '0{}x'.format((multiple + 1) * 2))
'075a80'
```